# Count variable not working

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, iterator

I am writing a program to take in a tweet as input and return a value of the unique hashtags used in the tweet. However in the countUniqueHashtags method, my hashtagCount variable will only return a value of 1 if the input contains hashtags(even if there is more than one) and a value of 0 if the input doesn't contain any hashtags.

```
public class UniqueHashtagCounter 
{

static ArrayList<String> uniqueHashTags = new ArrayList<String>();

int numberOfTweetsToFollow;
public String tweetSpace = "";
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public int getTweetsToFollow() 
        {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of Tweets you wish to follow: ");
        numberOfTweetsToFollow = in.nextInt();
        return numberOfTweetsToFollow;
        }

    public String tweetsInput()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= numberOfTweetsToFollow ; ++i)
        {
            if(in.hasNextLine()){
                tweetSpace = tweetSpace + in.nextLine();
            }   
        }
            return tweetSpace;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> populateArray()
    {
        uniqueHashTags.add(tweetSpace);
        for(String s: uniqueHashTags)
            s.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        for(int x = 0; x < uniqueHashTags.size(); x++){
        countUniqueHashtags(uniqueHashTags);}
        return uniqueHashTags;
    }

    static void countUniqueHashtags(ArrayList<String> strings)
    {
        int hashtagCount = uniqueHashTags.size();
        ListIterator<String> listIterator = strings.listIterator();
        while(listIterator.hasNext())
            {
                String e = listIterator.next();
                if(e.startsWith("#"))
                    hashtagCount = hashtagCount + 1;
            }
        System.out.println("The number of unique hashtags is: " + hashtagCount);
    }
```

Comment: This code is incomplete, it does not even compile. Can you provide a complete piece of code which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Use a set instead of a list to hold the unique hashtags. Sets cannot contain duplicates.

Comment: @shimonRachlenko, the main method isn't included but it literally just calls each method here, in the order they're listed listed.

    public static void main(String[] args) {
  UniqueHashtagCounter uhc = new   UniqueHashtagCounter();
  uhc.getTweetsToFollow();
  uhc.tweetsInput();
  uhc.populateArray();

Comment: @JamesB This is a project for school and I can only use the java api ArrayList or LinkedList.

Comment: Ok but your current solution does not cater for the same hashtag being used more than once in the same tweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My hashtagCount variable will only return a value of 1 if the input contains hashtags(even if there is more than one) and a value of 0 if the input doesn't contain any hashtags"

That's because you are using `startsWith()`:

```
if(e.startsWith("#"))
hashtagCount = hashtagCount + 1;
```

You need to loop through the string and count the hashtag characters:

```
for(int i=0; e.length();i++){
   if(e.charAt(i)=='#') hashtagcount++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that solved my issue. I tried using a for loop above the original if(e.startsWith("#")) line but I couldn't get that to work.